# ¿Por qué no avanza mi reloj hecho en JS?

Tags: javascript

Estoy replicando un reloj con este código:

```
    var today = new Date();
    var hr = today.getHours();
    var min = today.getMinutes();
    var sec = today.getSeconds();
    ap = (hr < 12) ? "<span>AM</span>" : "<span>PM</span>";
    hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
    hr = (hr > 12) ? hr - 12 : hr;
    //Add a zero in front of numbers<10
    hr = checkTime(hr);
    min = checkTime(min);
    sec = checkTime(sec);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + ap;
    
    var months = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Deciembre'];
    var days = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];
    
    var curWeekDay = days[today.getDay()];
    var curDay = today.getDate();
    var curMonth = months[today.getMonth()];
    var curYear = today.getFullYear();
    var date = curWeekDay+", "+curDay+" "+curMonth+" "+curYear;
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
    
    var time = setTimeout(function(){ startTime() }, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Ese es el código original, y el reloj si funciona actualizándose en tiempo real
Ej:
[image: Resultado del código original]

Este es mi código adaptado y un poco más actualizado:

```
const getDate = () => { //Obtener fecha
    let date = new Date();
    // return `${date.getDate()}-${('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${date.getFullYear()}`; //Otenemos la fecha actual
    const meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Deciembre'];
    const dias = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];
    
    let dia = dias[date.getDay()];
    let fecha = date.getDate();
    let mes = meses[date.getMonth()];
    let anio = date.getFullYear();
    
    return `${dia}, ${fecha} ${mes} ${anio}`;
}
fecha.textContent = getDate(); //asignamos la fecha al elemento

// ***********************
let destinoHora = document.getElementById('hora');
let getHour = () => { //obtener hora
    
    let hora = new Date(); 

    let hr = hora.getHours();
    let min = hora.getMinutes();
    let seg = hora.getSeconds();
    
    
    amPM = (hr < 10) ? 'AM' : 'PM';
    hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
    hr = (hr > 12) ? hr -12 : hr;
    
    hr = verificarCeros(hr);
    min = verificarCeros(min);
    seg = verificarCeros(seg);
    
    // let tiempo = setTimeout(function(){ getHour() }, 500);
    let tiempo = setTimeout(function(){ getHour() }, 500);
    return `${hr}:${min} ${amPM}`; 
    
}
verificarCeros= (i) => {
    if (i < 10) {
        i =  '0' + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Salida de mi código:

[image: Salida de mi código que n avanza los segundos visualmente.]

Si saca la hora y fecha, pero no se actualiza, es decir, no corren los segundos y por ende tampoco actualiza a los minutos.

¿Alguien podría orientarme? Aparentemente no hay error, pienso que el error podría estar en el setTimeOut, pero está igual al del código original, y sí muestra lo que necesito, la fecha y hora, pero lo que quiero es que se vaya actualizando como en tiempo real, el mío queda estático, y tengo que recargar la página para que se actualice los valores.

Comment: En mi opinion tu primera version de codigo parece mejor estructurada que la nueva, si bien las funciones flecha son muy interesantes y compactas de usar no se si ayuden en este caso, yo dejaria el let y el const obviamente.

Comment: Sobre porque no funciona... basicamente es porque estas llamando siempre a una funcion vacia en el `setTimeout`, recuerda que cualquier objeto tiene su referencia propia, entonces cuando le intentas pasar una `funcion` que se llama igual que la otra la funcion,  falla, y falla en este caso porque ambas son distintas a pesar de tener el mismo nombre, basicamente aunque tengan el mismo nombre no son las mismas.

Comment: Creo que tiene que ver el hecho de que una es una `function` comun y otra es una funcion `flecha`, esto hace que no sean iguales por definicion.

Comment: porque en vez de un timeout no usas un setinterval que cada 1 seg te genere un new date

Comment: Comentario totalmente no-relevante: El OP dice que está replicando a partir del código original y todos le responden como si fuese el autor de ambas versiones :P

Comment: Te agradezco tu respuesta, de acuerdo a todo lo que me comentas he hecho las adaptaciones pertinentes, Muchas gracias,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el código funciona perfectamente, lo que te ocurre es que `getHour()` no imprime en pantalla el resultado, solo actualiza la hora internamente. Además `verificarCeros()` tiene que estar antes de `getHour()` para poder usarlo dentro. Le he añadido a la salida los segundos para que sea más fácil ver que funciona.

```js
let getDate = () => { //Obtener fecha
    let date = new Date();
    // return `${date.getDate()}-${('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${date.getFullYear()}`; //Otenemos la fecha actual
    const meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Deciembre'];
    const dias = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];
    
    let dia = dias[date.getDay()];
    let fecha = date.getDate();
    let mes = meses[date.getMonth()];
    let anio = date.getFullYear();
    
    return `${dia}, ${fecha} ${mes} ${anio}`;
}
let fecha = document.getElementById('fecha');
fecha.textContent = getDate(); //asignamos la fecha al elemento

// ***********************
let verificarCeros= (i) => {
    if (i < 10) {
        i =  '0' + i;
    }
    return i;
}
let getHour = () => { //obtener hora
    
    let hora = new Date(); 

    let hr = hora.getHours();
    let min = hora.getMinutes();
    let seg = hora.getSeconds();
    
    
    amPM = (hr < 10) ? 'AM' : 'PM';
    hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
    hr = (hr > 12) ? hr -12 : hr;
    
    hr = verificarCeros(hr);
    min = verificarCeros(min);
    seg = verificarCeros(seg);
    
    //  let tiempo = setTimeout(function(){ getHour() }, 500);
    let tiempo = setTimeout(function(){ destinoHora.textContent=getHour() }, 500);
    return `${hr}:${min}:${seg} ${amPM}`; 
    
}
let destinoHora = document.getElementById('hora');
destinoHora.textContent = getHour();
```

```html
<div id="fecha"></div>
<div id="hora"></div>
<script></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido muchísimo este, agradezco inmensamente tu respuesta, he hecho las adaptaciones como sugieres, y  ahora está completamente funcional como quiero.

Answer (score 1):

Recomiendo que eches un ojo a la función `.setInterval()`. Puedes ver un ejemplo de su utilización aplicada a relojes en JavaScript **[en el siguiente enlace](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=847:ejemplo-reloj-javascript-settimeout-cleartimeout-setinterval-animacion-requestanimationframe-cu01164e&catid=78&Itemid=206)**.

En **[la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setInterval)** te puede quedar claro el uso que se le suele dar, así como los parámetros que contiene:

Con ello, conseguirás que la función sea ejecutada en un intervalo de tiempo que tú definas (en el segundo parámetro, y el cual debe ser **1000** en caso de que quieras hacer un reloj) y se sobreescriba el resultado continuamente, simbolizando la función realizada por un reloj digital.

No confundir esta función con `.setTimeOut()`, la cual tiende a ejecutarse una vez y puede resultar útil para otros casos, pero no para este.

Como detalle adicional, la primera versión de tu código me resulta menos compleja de leer, aunque probaría a poner `let` y `const` en vez de `var`.

¡Espero que puedas resolver pronto tu problema!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu sugerencia, de cierto modo he hecho las implementaciones como comentas.